# Can a Silverlight app receive multiple callbacks from one call?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, callback

I have data on a remote server.  I can query it asynchronously from, say, a console app  passing it a callback reference and it will return the data in batches, calling the callback once for each batch.  When I send the query, I won't know how many items are being returned, so I won't know how many batches, though I will know the batch size (apart from the last one, of course).

But I need to get the data to a Silverlight app.  I'd like to send the query and get the data in the original batches as there can be a number of seconds between each batch being returned.

Can I make a single call from a Silverlight app to a WCF service, which then calls my remote server and then, for each callback it gets from the remote server, call back to my Silverlight app?

Please don't suggest changes to the remote server as it's not possible.  I can't query to count the items as it's virtually as expensive as retrieveing them (as, essentially, that's what I'd have to do), so I can't do anything to know the number of batches.

Answer (score 0):

use a duplex binding [How to: Build a Duplex Service for a Silverlight Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28VS.95%29.aspx)